# Reading through a list in a txt file and output each value in the list to a new txt file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

So I have a script which essentially compares values and then output a report with the final values. It outputs them in to a list which is not what I want. Ideally i want to be able to have each value on a separate line one by one. So far my code is as follows :

```py
    def readIntoList(path):
        with open(path, "r") as text1:
            lines = text1.readlines()
            result = []
            for l in lines:
                l_list = l.replace("\n", "").split(" ")
                result.extend(l_list)

        return result

    
    def Diff(li1, li2):
        f = open("final-output.txt", "w")
        f.write(str(list(set(li2) - set(li1))))




    if __name__ == '__main__':
        a = readIntoList('file2.txt')
        b = readIntoList('file3.txt')
        result = Diff(a, b)
```

The function Diff is what outputs the following in final-output.txt :

```
['07577930503', '07577930502', '07577930500', '07577985801']
```

I want each number to be on a single line

Comment: Three backticks for a code-block. [Formatting help](/help/formatting). Please fix the indent of your python code.

Comment: `for elem in list(set(li2) - set(li1)): f.write(str(elem)+'\n')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your "Diff" function code to:

```
def Diff(li1, li2):
    f = open("final-output.txt", "w")
    listOfValues = list(set(li2) - set(li1))
    for value in listOfValues:
        f.write(str(value) + "\n")
```